# How can I remove duplicate photos in Camera Roll?

Tags: iphone, photos

I got a new phone and they transferred all my photos over.  The machine they used to transfer from the iphone 4s to iphone 5s died right as it was finishing so we started all over.  Now I have duplicates and they're in a random order. Is there any way to either group duplicates together or reorder them?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just connect your iphone device to a desktop and, depending on your os, use a duplicate finder. These apps organize your photo collection pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid duplicates is to select the images you want to create new folder  and import them to save PDF to ibook. Do this by selecting the image(s) you want, select the upload icon a select save PDF to ibook. You will have them in a separate folder from your photo app but at least you know you will have one folder without the duplicates.